# Datagridview dataload when searching

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a datagridview which displays data from database. I have added a a textbox as a searchbox and added a text changed event. In that event I have written Search query with 'LIKE' based on text in textbox. So when I type a character it will instantly search the database and display in datagridview.

But my problem is, for large amount of data, for example a million rows, this text changed event hangs the datagridview. cant display data to datagridview fastly. Any way to speed up the process?

Comment: **1)** Usually, `TextChanged` is not a suitable event for search in database because the user may want to search for 'something', so they will type 9 characters and you will search 9 times between thousands records, while you can search just once when they press Enter.  **2)** When the result of search may be too many records, it's better to apply a paging strategy, for example take top 50 records and show them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a BackgroundWorker to search my data and handle result only if the box content didn't change in the mean time. I would also add a delay on search to avoid useless search. Actually, when needed this kind of search i prefer handle keydown on Enter or/and a button to be sure that we search when we want to.